# Cassandra ReadTimeoutException on querying based on timestamp

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have Cassandra db table records

```
create table records (
id text,
cachedtime timestamp,
data list<frozen<RecordType>>,
PRIMARY KEY (id, cachedtime)       
AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY (cachedtime DESC);
```

RecordType is UDT , cachedtime is clustering key and TTL for each record is 60 minutes.

We are hitting ReadTimeoutException, on querying below select query with consistency level LOCAL_QUORUM with replication factor 2.

```
select * from records where id= "11" and cachedTime < now 

com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra   
timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (2 responses were 
required but only 1 replica responded)
```

Can anyone help me why i am hitting this exception. please also advise on query based on timstamp with no lower limit  will it cause performance issue?

please advise

Comment: A network problem?

Comment: How many rows are you expecting to be returned, and how many are stored with a partition key of 11?

Comment: can you include `cfhistogram` and `cfstats` (nodetool) for the table? Along with output of `nodetool status`